# How to merge two xml tags into one xml using apache camel bindy

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, camel-http

My problem is I have two different positions in my flat file with "|" seperated string. Position 2 and 3 refer to description. I want to generate xml with both descriptions appended to one description and return one DESC tag with both descriptions.

**Input Source:**

```
UN|2.1  |AEROSOLS
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<TEST>
<STATE>UN</STATE>
<DESC>2.1 AEROSOLS</DESC>
</TEST>
```

**OUTPUT I'M GETTING:**

```
    <TEST>
    <STATE>UN</STATE>
    <DESC_ONE>2.1 AEROSOLS</DESC_ONE>
    <DESC_TWO>AEROSOLS<DESC_TWO>
    </TEST>
```

**TEST.java**

```
@Data
public class TEST {


    @DataField(pos = 1, name = "STATE", required = true)
    private String STATE;

    @DataField(pos = 2, name = "DESC",required = true)
    private String DESC_ONE;

    @DataField(pos = 3, name = "DESC",required = true)
    private String DESC_TWO;


}
```

**Converter.java**

```
                            from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            log("Received input from file and body is ${body}").
                            unmarshal(bindyBeanConfig.bindyCsvDataFormat3280()).
                            process(new Processor()  {
                                @Override
                                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                                    TEST test = exchange.getIn().getBody(TEST.class);
                                    DESC_ONE descOne = test.getTEST();
                                    DESC_TWO descTwo = descOne.getDESC_ONE();

                                    String description = descOne.getDESC_ONE() + descTwo.getDESC_TWO();

                                    descOne.set_DESCONE(description);

                                    exchange.getIn().setBody(descTwo);

                                }
                            }).
```

Comment: I don't know much about `apche-camel` , nonetheless you can have another DataField in `TEST` say `DESC` , and you can set `DESC` instead of `DESC_ONE` in `Converter.java` , further before calling `exchange.getIn().setBody(descTwo);` you should set `DESC_ONE` and `DESC_TWO` to `null`.

Comment: @BHAWANISINGH I made changes based on your suggestions.It worked. Thanks!!

Comment: have update it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about `apache-camel` , nonetheless you can have another `DataField` in `TEST` say `DESC` , and you can set `DESC` instead of `DESC_ONE` in `Converter.java` , further before calling `exchange.getIn().setBody(descTwo);` you should set `DESC_ONE` and `DESC_TWO` to `null`.